# .NET Core 3.1 System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, sql-server

.Net.Core 3.1

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-IOHENDV\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO accounts (login, email, password) VALUES('"+ login+"', '"+ email+"', '"+ password+"'";
            command.Connection = connection;
        }
```

При выполнении функции появляется ошибка:
Could not load file or assembly 'D:\server\System.Data.SqlClient.resources.dll'. Не удается найти указанный файл.
System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.

Как её исправить?

Comment: Как подключали библиотеку к проекту? Отключите и поставьте NuGet пакет https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Выдает ошибку теперь Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.
Как её исправить?

Comment: А какая у вас платформа стоит? Linux? Закройте проект, удалите папки bin и obj и пересоберите проект. Может быть глюк.

Comment: Windows, пересобрал, не помогло. 
Как бы проект собирается, но при обращении к методу в котором заключен код, вылетает эта ошибка.

Comment: Целевая платформа какая в проекте? Поделитесь секретом?

Comment: Игровой сервер, основанный на Class Library C# .NET Core 3.1

Comment: откройте .csproj файл и скажите TargetFramework/TargetPlatform

Comment: Кстати, совет, не храните пароли в открытом виде, это небезопасно. Если кто-то украдет у вас базу, он узнает все пароли. Используйте хэширование, например SHA256. Получите хэш (массив байт), его преобразуете в строку Base64 и ее уже сохраните в базу. Обратная расшифровака невозможна, поэтому чтобы сверить пароль, нужно будет стелать хэш из введенного и сравнить с сохраненным хэшом. Так делают все на всех серверах. Задача решается в лишних 6 строк кода, 3 на сохранить, 3 на сверить.

Comment: <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>

Comment: ничего необычного, должно работать, если вы ничего не поломали в проекте

Comment: я столкнулся с тем, что я неправильно собирал проект. Это привождило к тому, что при запуске файл Microsoft.Data.SqlClient не находился, появлялась ошибка "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient'". Оказалось, надо было правильно собирать, можно глянуть мой вопрос тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437427/