# Net Core и MS SQL + Docker: откуда берётся ошибка "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, docker, .net-core

Господа,
коротко: не получается запустить проект, который из докер-образа коннектится к MS SQL - базе данных, при этом появляется ошибка

```
    Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
    'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'. 
    The system cannot find the file specified.

    File name: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'
```

Поиск по сети по формулировке ошибки приводит к достаточно дурацким топикам [типа такого](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1397)

Попытка использовать прредыдущую версию Microsoft.Data.SqlClient или даже использовать Net Core 5.0 вместо 6.0 - тоже ничего не даёт.

**Что делать?**

Теперь подробно.

я делаю вот что: я пишу на Net Core протейшую консольную программу, которая должна подключиться к базе данных и выполнить запрос.

Для этого вопроса я сделал отдельный repo

https://github.com/junecat/SqlDemoCsharp

Буквально, вот её "содержательная часть":

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlCnStr))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(fPath))
        w.WriteLine("Conection opened!");

    const string sqlSel = "select count(*) from Table1";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSel, conn))
    {
        int rez = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(fPath))
            w.WriteLine($"count = {rez}");
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы создать это проект - я пользуюсь простейшими командами

`dotnet new console`
и
`dotnet add package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

Потом я в проект вписываю немного кода, сохраняю его, компилирую, запускаю - всё работает!

Под виндой.

В файл выводится

```
    Hello, from SQL test program...
    Conection opened!
    count = 6
```

Теперь я пробую собрать этот проект в виртульной машине с линуксом:

```
    dotnet publish -c release
    cd /home/konst/SqlDemoCsharp/SqlDemoCsharp/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/
    dotnet SqlDemoCsharp.dll
```

Всё отлично, в `Logs/Logfile.log` видны те же самые три строчки, свидетельствующие о том, что проект запустился, подключился к SQL и выполнил запрос.

А теперь пробую сделать то жа самое в докер-образе.

Собственно, весь процесс сборки-и-запуска содержится в двух Dockerfile и в двух sh-файликах:

Сборка:

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM ubuntu:latest
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y wget
    RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
    ENV DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
    RUN apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
    # dotnet sdk is installed!

    COPY ./SqlDemoCsharp /App/SqlDemoCsharp
    WORKDIR /App/SqlDemoCsharp
    RUN dotnet publish -c release
    CMD mkdir /App/publish-output/
    CMD cp -r /App/SqlDemoCsharp/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/* /App/publish-output
```

sh-файл:

```
    docker build -t build_sql_demo-image -f Dockerfile .

    docker run -it --name build_sql_demo-cont  -v ~/SqlDemoCsharp/publish-output:/App/publish-output -d build_sql_demo-image
```

Запуск:

Dockerfile2:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
    ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
    RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
    COPY publish-output/* /App/
    WORKDIR /App
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SqlDemoCsharp.dll"]
```

sh-файл:

```
    docker build -t run_sql_demo-image -f Dockerfile2 .

    docker run -it --name run_sql_demo-cont  -v ~/SqlDemoCsharp/Logs/:/App/Logs/  -d run_sql_demo-image
```

После запуска контейнера в лог ничего не записывается, а выполнив `docker logs run_sql_demo-cont` я вижу злополучную ошибку:

```
    Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
    Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'. 
    The system cannot find the file specified.

    File name: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'
```

Причем, понятное дело, то файла с точным именем `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` у меня в процессе сборки не образуется, но файл
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
встречается аж трижды:

```
konst@pve:~/SqlDemoCsharp$ find . -name Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
./publish-output/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp3.1/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
./publish-output/runtimes/unix/lib/netcoreapp3.1/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
./publish-output/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
```

Если выполнить поиск по файловой системе той виртуальной машины с линуксом, на которой приложение запускается - то видно, что там те же DLL - ки лежат по тем же путям:

```
konst@ucs117:~$ cd SqlDemoCsharp/
konst@ucs117:~/SqlDemoCsharp$ sudo find . -name Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
./SqlDemoCsharp/bin/Release/net6.0/runtimes/unix/lib/netcoreapp3.1/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
./SqlDemoCsharp/bin/Release/net6.0/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp3.1/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
./SqlDemoCsharp/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/runtimes/unix/lib/netcoreapp3.1/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
./SqlDemoCsharp/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp3.1/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
./SqlDemoCsharp/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
./SqlDemoCsharp/bin/Release/net6.0/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
```

Здесь в  выводе команды find - 6 строчек вместо трех, но это из за того, что есть отдельно каталдог с приложением, и отдельно катадлог Publish

Также, я прочитал такое вот "[руководство MS по устанению неисправностей](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver16)", но никакие советы оттуда не помогли.

В общем, загадка природы. Понятно, что докер по какой то причине "не видит" лежащего "рядом" (а точнее - в той же самой диреториии, что и DLL с самой аппликухой) файла `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Йес!
Йес!
Это получилось!

В процессе написания вопроса я решил проверить гипотезу "А что будет, если при сборке указать конкретную платформу, под которую надо собрать проект?"

Это делается изменением команды с

`dotnet publish -c release`

на более полную команду, в которой указана целевая платформа linux-x64:

`dotnet publish --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained true -c release`

то есть, добавился ключик **--runtime linux-x64** (и вслед за этим пришлось добавить ключ `--self-contained true` - из за варнинга, который появлялся при сборке)

После такого уточнения директория, куда выводится собранный проект изменилась с

```
    /App/SqlDemoCsharp/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/
```

на

```
    /App/SqlDemoCsharp/bin/Release/net6.0/linux-x64/publish/
```

и при этом собранный код стал нормально запускаться в контейнере!

Да, надо добавить, что кол-во файлов в директории `publish-output` при сборке с такими ключиками значительно возросло!

Я поместил примеры правильных файлов для сборки в репозиторий с вопросом.

Comment: Ну вы просто собрали дотнет целиком в саму сборку приложения. Это значит что докер просто не видит дотнета, установленного на машине, ну ли бо на него ссылаетесь неправильно. По идее framework-dependent сборка должна работать в докере без проблем.

Comment: @aepot - Да, до этого все "хелловорлды" работали без уточнения платформы linux-x64. Почему так-фиг знает, если какое то другое решение попадётся-киньте им в меня?